# Can I run a regression model if I don't have the same years of data across all variables?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I am still identifying co-variables for my regression model. 
I now have a dataset across 10 years. But one variable (self-rated physical health) does not appear in all the 10 years. According to the theory and previous research done by others, self-rated health condition is one of the most important determining variables, which means that I cannot simply omit this variable. So, how could I deal with this problem? 
Thank you!

Comment: 1) Google for "missing data", "multiple imputation"  etc. 2) Then ask us a more specific question

Answer (score 0):

You can just use it as a predictor whenever you have it and ignore it otherwise.

You can also test if the value from previous years could be used instead of the missing value.